# How to group data returned from Network api in rxjava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am getting data response from news api and I need to show those data in recycler view by grouping the data on the basis of source.

Basically I am getting List of ArticalDto and I want to convert this list to List as I need to group the data by source and show in recycler view in multiple view. I was thinking to use either GroupBy or Map for this but not getting exact approach. Here is the Code which I wrote for getting the data from network.

```
class ContentListViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
    internal val result = MutableLiveData<Result<ArticlesDto>>()

    /**
     * Fetches news from sources.
     * You do not need to understand this implementation in order to complete the assignment.
     * All the updates (response) are posted to the [result] liveData.
     */
    fun fetchNews(params: ContentParams = ContentParams()) {
        NewsApiRepository(apiKey = apiKey).getEverything(
            q = params.q,
            sources = params.sources,
            domains = params.domains,
            language = params.language,
            sortBy = params.sortBy,
            pageSize = params.pageSize,
            page = params.page
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .toFlowable()
            .subscribe(
                { result.value = Result.success(it) },
                {
                    Log.e("Error", it.cause?.message ?: "")
                    result.value = Result.failure(it)
                }
            ).disposeOnClear()
    }
}
```

Can any one suggest me how can I achieve this using rxjava? I can do it by converting the list to Hashmap first and then again convert it to list but want to use rxjava for this.

Answer (score 0):

make your new api reponse pojo class..
then used below code..

```
    var categoryResult: MutableLiveData<List<CategoryModel>> = MutableLiveData()
```

api calling..

```
fun getCategoryData(storeId: String) {

    if (ConnectivityUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplication())) {
        showProgressDialog.postValue(true)
        storeData = storeId
        launch {
            appApiInterface
                    .getCategories(storeId)
                    .with(schedulerProvider)
                    .subscribe(
                            { result ->
                                showProgressDialog.postValue(false)
                                if (result.categories != null)
                                    categoryResult.postValue(result.categories)
                                else
                                    showNoData()
                            },
                            { e ->
                                showProgressDialog.postValue(false)
                                interFragmentInterface?.showDialog(e.getErrorMessage(getApplication()))
                            }
                    )
        }
    } else {
        interFragmentInterface!!.showDialog(getApplication<Application>().getString(R.string.error_message_network))
    }
}
```

after that in activity or fragment observer used..

```
viewModel.categoryResult.observe(this, Observer { it ->
// here set api list of data into adapter class insert method.
// here set your adapter code.
    })
```

used viewModel is more easy.

Comment: I need to group the data which has been returned from the getEverything API so you are calling getCategorie data.